# SpringCore - Can I use @ContextConfiguration to load beans in main class instead of creating ApplicationContext obj to load bean?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, applicationcontext

I read this statement on Spring doc

> @ContextConfiguration defines class-level metadata that is used to determine how to load and configure an ApplicationContext for integration tests.
>   Specifically, @ContextConfiguration declares the application context resource locations or the annotated classes that will be used to load the context.

Then, I try to load the application context in main class (not test class) by putting the @ContextConfiguration at the top of class, however Spring can not load the bean definition.

**AppJavaBasedConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class AppJavaBasedConfig {

    @Bean
    public IStringUtil stringUtil() {
        return new StringUtil();
    }

    @Bean
    public App app() {
        return new App();
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=AppJavaBasedConfig.class)
public class App {

    @Autowired
    private IStringUtil stringUtil;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppJavaBasedConfig.class);
        // App app = context.getBean(App.class);
        App app = new App();
        app.stringUtil.lower("AAA");
    }
}
```

It throws the NullPointerException.

So, can we use this annotation in main class?

Comment: @ContextConfiguration is for loading the context in integration test. you should not use it anywhere other than stereotype annotations

Answer (score 2):

short answer is no. it is a conceptual problem. 
Spring can load all the bean which are annotated with @Configuration; but who would instantiate/start spring container?

since you have `public static void main` I assume the endproduct is jar which would run on the command line as `java -jar`.

when you try to execute `java -jar` the method that gets executed is the `public static void main` (provided you have all the manifest correctly) and the first thing you should be doing is instantiating spring container crtl+c from your question

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppJavaBasedConfig.class);
     App app = context.getBean(App.class);

}
```

if you don't want to do all these you could make use of [spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need IStringUtil stringUtil in App.java and test something  you can make use of @PostContruct or init-method attribute of @Bean to get called during the bean `s lifecycle  :

```
@Component
public class App {

    @Autowired
    private IStringUtil stringUtil;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        stringUtil.lower("AAA");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quickly rep, however [test something] is not my goal, I really want to load the bean definitions. Btw, maybe your last comment about the function of this annotation should take into account in this case.